# Linux crawl sitemap and check page itself + images + internal links for 404

Tags: web-crawler, http-status-code-404, scrapy

I know several ways of crawling using Xenu or other. But there must be a better or smarter way of doing this.

I would

- like to crawl oour site based on the sitemap
- Check for
- a) the page itself 404?
- b) internal links without params on the page itself 404?
- c) all images: do they exist?

One could write a PHP script or other. But are there any ready made tools, scripts or maybe Curl that we could use to do this?

THX!

Answer (score 0):

[StormCrawler](http://stormcrawler.net) is an open source web crawler implemented mainly in Java. It handles sitemaps so you could use is to crawl your site and check for 404 errors.

Comment: Apache. We run nginx.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Crowlet (full disclosure: I am the maintainer) to check the return stats and response time of URLs in your sitemap. It does not support internal links and images as well.

It is basically a one-liner with Docker, and can return a specific exit code based issues encountered, or be parsed as JSON (logstash, ...).

The project's here: https://github.com/Pixep/crowlet.

And an example to look for non-200:

```
# Return with code `150` if any page has a status != 200
docker run -it --rm aleravat/crowlet --crawl-hyperlinks --crawl-images --non-200-error 150 https://foo.bar/sitemap.xml
```

Comment: Would you mind documenting how to use the "override-host: option?

Comment: The intent was to override the domain to be able to use a sitemap while targetting a dev/staging/other host than the one listed in the sitemap. Checking the code however, I don't see it referenced. I don't recall, but it might have been a leftover. Is that something you needed?